# Custom Attribute to determine if method can process

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, attributes

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to setup a Custom Attribute to determine if a method call can process.  What I'm wanting is similar to the `[Authorize()]` attribute that I use in my MVC3 application.

Basically, I have a COM Object that I'm interfacing (3rd Party DMS Software) with and I want to make sure that the user hasn't closed the program before I process the contents of the method.  I can wrap the calls in a `try/catch` or I can wrap a method that checks the `application.running`, but I like the attribute functionality and the simple markup (if it's required).

All the tutorials/documentation that I've found so far is how to markup a method/class with properties (they generally use a string in the tutorials) and then access those string values later in code.

---

This is just not something that I'm wanting to do if at all possible.  Again, in MVC3/4 you can do...

```
[Authorize()]
public class ControllerClass : Controller {
   public ActionResult Index(){ return View(); }
   ....etc....
}
```

In this example Index always has to be be called by someone that passes `Authorize`.  What I'm not sure is if this is required to instantiate the class or call the method.

So after all of that my question is simply.  Can something similar to `Authorize()` be implemented for a C# WinForms Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can implement it via [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) framework like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). Sample:

```
[Serializable]
public class LogAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        if (!application.running)
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Method {0} is not allowed to call when application is not running.", args.Method.Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there are some licensing costs with PostSharp I'll see if I can't find another AOP framework that's open source.  Thanks for pointing towards aop though I'll post back if I find something

Comment: @Jared looks like Method and Property aspects are available for commercial usage in starter edition. http://www.sharpcrafters.com/purchase/compare

Comment: Yea, I saw that, but it's specifically what I'm wanting to get away from.  As it stands I could simply do a `if(!application.running) return; //or return something depending on the method`.  I'm hoping to get away from the need for a call or annotation on each method.  It's a small thing, but something I was interested in.